# How to Detect an Application launch and Exit in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I would like to find out how our Android app can listen when some application is launch (and exit) in an Android device by a user(How to listen to it through Broadcast Receivers or any other way)?

I have searched a lot but not find any satisfactory solution. Please help in this regard. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: you want to know about the applications that was written by you or the ones you downloaded from market ?? if it was written by you then you can write sendBroadcast when the application is launched

Comment: It can be any App(market, non-market, mine or anything else installed on the phone.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any default way to do that by broadcasts. 
You could try using `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses`

Correction: Listen for the broadcasts android.intent.action.MAIN and android.intent.category.LAUNCHER. Create a broadcast receiver and in the onReceive method check to see the name of the application that is started.

Comment: (Attempting to listen for android.intent.action.MAIN - that's not going to work btw)